# Bibtex references, citing from same reference but different page

Tags: bibtex, achemso

I am using TeXnicCenter, Miktex 2.9 and have BibTeX for using references (`bibliographystyle{achemso}`).

I am writing my master thesis and I would like to refere to the same reference, but with different page related to that reference.
I would like to have it like this:

> ex. text with references: Hello^1a, how are you^1b

How it should look like in the bibliography:

> 1. author, title, publisher, year, pages (a) 2-4, (b) 60-78.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: Are you sure this is really what you want? Imagine a reader who has the relevant book on his desk, maybe he would prefer reading "as shown in [1], pages 60-78", rather than having to go to the end of your document to see which pages you are referencing.